# Does initial "-e " have a special meaning in a shell variable assignment?

Tags: bash, shell

I don't seem to be able to assign a string that begins with "-e" or "-E" to a bash shell variable:

```
$ options="-e stuff"
$ echo $options
stuff
```

Other letters work fine:

```
$ options="-g stuff"
$ echo $options
-g stuff
```

What is the reason for this?

Comment: Your command is substituted to  `echo -e stuff ` and `-e` is a valid echo flag

Comment: See: `help echo`

Comment: Use `printf` instead: `printf '%s\n' "$options"`.

Comment: @Axnyff, ...not *that* valid. See the POSIX spec for `echo` at http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html -- it explicitly specifies that *Implementations shall not support any options*. `-n` is explicitly called out as causing undefined behavior when used as first operand -- but there's no such note for `-e`, and any shell that does anything other than print `-e` on output is in violation of the pertinent specification. This is one of the few places where bash breaks the POSIX spec rather than extending it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should quote your variable:

```
echo "${options}"
```

otherwise it's being expanded to

```
echo -g stuff
```

which is being interpreter by `echo` as its `-e` option, which actually exists (see `man echo`), and that's why `-e` "did not work" while other letters you tried "did".

Comment: Quoting will not normally stop command-line utilities from interpreting `-` as a command-line flag indicator, because the utility has no way to know that the dash was quoted. It works in this specific case only because `echo` only recognises `-e` as a command-line flag if it is the entire option. You should not rely on ths behaviour.

Comment: This won't cause `options=-e; echo "$options"` to reliably print `-e` on bash.

Comment: @rici that's correct. Most commands would need `--` in such case or something like that. Yet, OP asked about `echo`...

Comment: @MarcinOrlowski: yes, OP asked about `echo` but even `echo` will misbehave with certain strings. In addition to Charles' example, try (for example) `options=-nene`. Anyway, the explanation of why quoting happens to work in this case seemed to me relevant.

Answer (score 2):

First: To reliably determine the value of a variable in bash, use `declare -p`, not `echo`. Thus:

```
declare -p options
```

will emit something like:

```
declare -- options="-e stuff"
```

This tells you much more than `echo` does:

- Because it's `declare --` rather than `declare -x`, you know that the variable is not exported.
- Because it's not `declare -a`, you know it's not giving you an array (`echo "$array"` will print only the first element of a shell array and ignore the rest).
- Because it's not `declare -i`, you know the value wasn't declared to be an integer... etc.

---

If you're only worried about the string case, but want to *ensure* that you get a printable value no matter which version of bash is in use (as some historical releases will not always guarantee printable escaping for values printed with `declare -p`), consider instead:

```
printf '%q=%q\n' options "$options"
```

...which will emit unambiguous output even if there are cursor control characters, newlines, or other non-textual contents in your string.

---

Follow the advice of [the POSIX specification for `echo`](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/echo.html), and use `printf` instead. To quote the **APPLICATION USAGE** section in full, emphasis added, noting that in bash, `-e` enables XSI-style interpretation of escape sequences:

> **It is not possible to use echo portably across all POSIX systems
>   unless** both -n (as the first argument) and **escape sequences are
>   omitted.**
>
> The printf utility can be used portably to emulate any of the
>   traditional behaviors of the echo utility as follows (assuming that
>   IFS has its standard value or is unset):
>
> The historic System V echo and the requirements on XSI implementations
>   in this volume of POSIX.1-2008 are equivalent to:
>
> ```
> printf "%b\n" "$*"
> ```
>
> The BSD echo is equivalent to:
>
> ```
> if [ "X$1" = "X-n" ]
> then
>     shift
>     printf "%s" "$*"
> else
>     printf "%s\n" "$*"
> fi
> ```
>
> New applications are encouraged to use `printf` instead of `echo`.

---

So, how does this apply to you? Since you want `-e` to be treated as data, not part of `echo`'s setup, the BSD, non-`-n` branch of that applies:

```
options="-e stuff"
printf '%s\n' "$options"
```